# Renaming files with various extensions

Tags: bash, sed, awk, rename

I have a folder of files which contains a variety of random file extensions as well as no extensions at all. I wish to strip the extensions from the file name. I feel I may be going a long winded way but I wanted to avoid using two lists and the move command as it cannot be conducted on-the-fly.

The code I am using will create a variable to keep the extension and I am trying to invoke the rename command with the sed syntax to strip the variable from the file.

```
for i in `ls`; do 
        blah=$(echo $i |awk -F . '{if (NF>1) {print $NF}}')
        echo \.$blah
        rename 's/\.$blah//' $i  

done
```

The error I am getting is: Global symbol "$blah" requires explicit package name at (eval 1) line 1

At this point I am going to build a csv with a before and after column and use it to strip the file name but for future reference I would like to know how to accomplish this.

I see allot of posts about using rename for a single or a few extensions:

```
rename 's/.mp3//' *.mp3
```

but due to the number of different extensions...

Comment: Just change your line for `rename "s/\.$blah//" $i`, that is, wrap with double quotes.

Answer (score 5):

Following `bash` command should do the job:

```
for f in *.*; do mv "$f" "${f%.*}"; done
```

Comment: @JakubM.: Yes. It removes the shortest suffix of `$f` that matches the regular expression `.*`. So, from last `.` until end of string.

Comment: pedantically, that's not a regular expression: it's a filename expansion pattern, or glob pattern

Answer (score 4):

`rename` in your system is implemented in Perl, that's where the error comes from. You used single quotes, which means the variable was not expanded, and Perl did not find the definition of a variable $blah.

Also, `` for i in `ls` `` might be wrong if your file names contain spaces. It is better to use a wildcard, as in

```
for i in *.*
```

What do you want to do for files whose names without extensions are identical, like `good.mp3` and `good.jpg`? Do you want to overwrite one of them?

To use `rename` on all files with extensions, you can try

```
rename 's/\..*//' *.*
```

It would still overwrite some files as noted before. Also, files with names like `a.b.c.d` would be renamed to `a` only.

Answer (score 2):

if you want, you can use the bash parameter expansion to strip the extension. Also you dont need and `ls` to get all the files

```
for i in *; do echo "$i to ${i%.*}" mv "$i" "${i%.*}"; done
```

Now for a.b.c -> a use "%%" , and for a.b, use "%" as above

Update : ( for file with space in name)

```
[[bash_prompt$]]$ ls -l
total 0
[[bash_prompt$]]$ touch "file space.sh" "another space .sh"
[[bash_prompt$]]$ ls
another space .sh  file space.sh
[[bash_prompt$]]$ for i in *; do mv "$i" "${i%%.*}"; done
[[bash_prompt$]]$ ls
another space   file space
```